# Responsive Designs Foundation/Bootstrap height setting best practice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Just wondering what exactly is the best practice for say, setting the height of a header in a responsive layout. Would you set it to the column, the row, or perhaps the element(s) nested inside the row. I know its a pretty basic question and there may not be a correct answer, but I am having trouble finding a consensus on this.

Is it best to use the framework in a completely detached way from other elements, eg, never add custom css to a row/col tag just use inner containers? What is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

I usually let the content set the height.

```
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<h1 class="padding_min-height_etc"><!-- h1 with a height / margin / padding etc -->
```

Although I have noticed others using classes set on the header itself.

```
<header id="overview" class="jumbotron subhead">
<div class="container">
<h1>Components</h1>
```

I was always taught to not use HTML tags to style content thought...